# reload form JFrame without setVisible

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

How to reload a form in a `JFrame`? I have two forms, `form1` and `form2`:

1. `form1` links to `form2` using:

   ```
   new form2().show(); 
   this.setVisible(false);
   ```
2. `form2` links to `form1` is success
3. The problem is when `form1` `form2` links to existing data are not shown.

I want to ask is there any other way than `setVisible()` method because it seems just to hide it.

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556) 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 3) And please, stop talking Netbeans and start talking Java.

Comment: Not been able to fully understand the term **"Reload a form in a JFrame" and I have two forms, form1 and form2**. I guess this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13110320/1057230) might can help you, if I guessed, what you thinking in the right sense :-)

Comment: i mean how to close jframe without using setvisible. because jframe setVisible just hide it.Like a restart in pc, jframe exit and re-open again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) to switch between forms. This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5655843/230513) navigates with buttons; this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6432291/230513) navigates with a combo. You can make navigation conditional based on what filled on your form.

Addendum: *Like a restart in pc,* `jframe` *exit and re-open again.*

Although `CardLayout` is *much* more flexible, but you can always empty the `Container`, add the desired components and invoke `validate()/repaint()`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5812981/230513).

Comment: i mean how to close jframe without using setvisible. because jframe setVisible just hide it.Like a restart in pc, jframe exit and re-open again.

Comment: @user1815938 : Again, I guess what you looking for is this [frameObject.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation(int)) or `JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`, that might can serve as an alternative, to the context you are presenting.

Comment: @user1815938: I've elaborated above; also consider Gagandeep Bali's suggestion.