# change jpanel if a button is clicked in jframe

Tags: java, oop, user-interface, jpanel, jbutton

i'm a beginner in GUI and i have a program that has menu on the left side which are jbuttons inside jpanel. how can i change the jpanel in the right side if i click one of the buttons in the menu? here are my codes:

for my menu:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Menu extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    static JButton btnRegister, btnVote, btnResult, btnView, btnSearch, btnLogout;
    JLabel lblLogo, lblTitle;
    ImageIcon imgLogo;
    static JPanel panelLogo, panelTitle, panelButtons, panelMENU;

    Menu(){
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(320, 700));

        btnRegister=new JButton("REGISTER");
        btnRegister.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(320, 90));
        btnVote=new JButton("VOTE");
        btnVote.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(320, 90));
        btnResult=new JButton("PARTIAL RESULT");
        btnResult.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(320, 90));
        btnView=new JButton("VIEW RECORDS");
        btnView.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(320, 90));
        btnSearch=new JButton("SEARCH");
        btnSearch.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(320, 90));
        imgLogo=new ImageIcon("logo.png");
        lblLogo=new JLabel(imgLogo);
        lblTitle=new JLabel("ELECTION YEAR 2765");

        panelLogo=new JPanel();
        panelTitle=new JPanel();
        panelButtons=new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 1));

        panelLogo.add(lblLogo);
        panelTitle.add(lblTitle);

        panelButtons.add(btnRegister);
        panelButtons.add(btnVote);
        panelButtons.add(btnResult);
        panelButtons.add(btnView);
        panelButtons.add(btnSearch);
        panelButtons.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        add(panelLogo, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(panelTitle, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(panelButtons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        btnRegister.addActionListener(this);
        btnView.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource().equals(btnRegister)){
            Main.frameMain.setSize(1200, 700);
            Main.frameMain.add(new PanelRegister(), BorderLayout.EAST);
            Main.frameMain.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        }
        if(e.getSource().equals(btnVote)){}
        if(e.getSource().equals(btnResult)){}
        if(e.getSource().equals(btnView)){
            Main.frameMain.setSize(1200, 700);
            Main.frameMain.add(new PanelView(), BorderLayout.EAST);
            Main.frameMain.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        }
        if(e.getSource().equals(Menu.btnSearch)){}
    }
}
```

for my main frame

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main{
    static JFrame frameMain;

    Main(){
        frameMain=new JFrame();

        frameMain.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        frameMain.setSize(320, 700);
        frameMain.setTitle("Election Year 2765");

        frameMain.add(new Menu());

        frameMain.setVisible(true);
        frameMain.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frameMain.setResizable(false);
        frameMain.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frameMain.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        new Main();
    }
}
```

**EDIT: I found this answer here [How do I hide the current JPanel and show a new one with a button in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13110094/how-do-i-hide-the-current-jpanel-and-show-a-new-one-with-a-button-in-java) but can i use this in `BorderLayout`?**

Comment: 1. For help sooner, please post an [mcve] 2. Use an `ActionListener` to respond to events like clicking on a `JButton` 3. To change the child components of `JPanel` after it is visible, you should follow the changes with calls to `revalidate` and `repaint`

Comment: @copeg can you tell me how to use `revalidate` and `repaint` ?